# Custom Search API "Try this API" Working?

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I was trying to use the "Try this API" interface here: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/reference/rest/v1/cse/list

All I am getting from it is 400- Bad Request errors. Does this still work?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Google's documentation on the API Explorer for background reference: https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/

There are 2 possible issues. Either you are not providing an API key, or you are not providing the Programmable Search Engine ID.

To fix the API key issue, just let Google generate one by ticking the 'API key' checkbox at the bottom under 'Credentials'.

To get the search engine ID, sign in to the [Programmable Search Engine Control Panel](https://programmablesearchengine.google.com/cse/all) and create a search engine. Copy the search engine ID and paste it in the `cx` field in the API explorer. The `cx` field is not optional.

Additionally, to use the standard fields, click on the `Show standard parameters` and enter your search terms under the `q` field to make a regular search query, rather than using the other search query specifications.